# Function that fails to be differentiable on a set of measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I've been trying to do the following question, but I've been unable to make any conclusions at all. If anyone could offer a suggestion, please do! It's appreciated.

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a set of Lebesgue measure zero. Show that there exists a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and increasing everywhere and that fails to be differentiable at each point in $E$.

Comment: As I read it, the question wants such a function for an arbitrary given set $E$ of measure $0$, not just a particular example.

Comment: Yes, it's any set of measure zero. Were it the Cantor set, we would be able to just consider the Cantor-Lebesgue function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Very good point!

Answer (score 8):

By outer regularity, there is a nested sequence of open sets $U_n$ so that
$E \subseteq U_n$ and $m(U_n) < 2^{-n}$.  Let
$$f(x) = x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(U_n \cap (-\infty, x))$$  To see that $f$ is non-differentiable on $E$, note that 
$(f(x+h) - f(x))/h \ge 1 + n$ if $h > 0$ and $(x, x+h) \subseteq U_n$.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks! Do you think it generalized to any abstract measure space $X$ and not just playing with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, or does this seem really important, based on the way you are choosing intervals? I think it will generalize, to $n$-dimensional Euclidean space at the very least.

Comment: I don't know how you're going to define "differentiable function" in an abstract measure space.

Comment: That had occurred to me after I had posed the question; I realize it didn't make sense. Sorry!

Comment: For future visitors: note that $f$ may be not differentiable at points outside of $E$ too; indeed the above function is not differentiable at all points of $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n\supseteq E$