# Function in $AC$ but not in $KC^1$

Tags: calculus, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

**Definition 1**: A function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is piecewise $C^1$, shortly $f\in KC^1([a,b])$, if exists a partition $a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b$ s.t. $f|_{(t_{k-1},t_k)}\in C^1([t_{k-1},t_k])$, for $k=1,\ldots,n$.

**Definition 2**: A function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous, shortly $f\in AC([a,b])$, if for every $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta$ s.t. if $\{[a_k,b_k]\}_{k=1}^n$, is a finite collection of disjoint intervals in $[a,b]$, it holds
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k)<\delta\quad\Rightarrow\quad\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)|<\epsilon
$$
Moreover, an important result states that $f\in AC([a,b])$ iff

- $f$ derivable in $[a,b]$ and
- $f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^xf'(t)dt\;$ for every $x\in[a,b]$

It is easy to prove that $KC^1[a,b]\subset AC[a,b]$ (i.e. every piecewise $C^1$ function is also absolutely continuous), but I can't find an exemple of a function $f\in AC([a,b])\setminus KC([a,b])$, so an absolutely continuous function which is not piecewise $C^1$.

Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: But if you are $C^1$ on $[t_0,t_1]$ and on $[t_1,t_2]$, then your are $C^1$ on $[t_0,t_2]$, no? I suppose you mean $C^1((t_{k-1},t_k))$, right ?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2298271/121671) is another example